# How to replace existing Swing UI module with Griffon based one in a legacy Java application?

Tags: java, groovy, legacy, porting, griffon

The application that I would like to revamp is pretty well organized. UI is separated into a module. UI controllers implement the interface `PropertyChangeListener`. When other modules want to have something happened in the UI they just fire `PropertyChangeEvents` on UI controllers not being aware what is behind them. Current implementations of injected `PropertyChangeListener`s could be easily replaced with Griffon controllers implementing the same interface.

Calling Java methods from Groovy is not a big deal so the communication from UI to the rest of the application shouldn't be a big deal.

Are there any tutorials or written down experiences with porting UI modules written in Swing to Griffon framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the upcoming Griffon 0.9.1 you can write model/view/controller artifacts with pure Java.
So, maybe it will be a good start point to port your application to Griffon.
Check out details here http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GRIFFON/Griffon+0.9.1#Griffon0.9.1-NonGroovyArtifacts

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I don't think there is anything for going from legacy Java Swing to Griffon. A project I was working on last year was in a similar state. At the SpringOne2GX conference I asked the Griffon authors about using Griffon from a legacy Swing application. They said that right now unfortunately Griffon was for greenfield applications only. This is something they hoped to get to but to my knowledge is still not possible. This was as of September 2009.

You might be able to get something to work but I think you would be the one writing the tutorial on how to do this.

Comment: Thumbs up for your uplifting voice. Thanks